# CSS select next two elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
...
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="last">...</li>

<li class="selected">...</li>  # <- this
<li>...</li>                   # <- this
<li class="last">...</li>      # <- this

<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="last">...</li>
....
```

So, basically groups of three `li`s, the last one with a specific class and in one of the groups the first `li` with a special class.

Is there a way with pure CSS to select the `li` with the `selected` class and the next two ones, marked in the above code?

I've managed to select the next one using `li.selected + li`, but this doesn't work for the one after that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply add another `+ li` to reach it:

```
li.selected, li.selected + li, li.selected + li + li
```

Comment: What CSS spec does this fall under?  Is it widely supported in browsers?  I need to file this away somewheres.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Doesn't work for me in current Chrome.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: It's CSS2, and has been supported for many years by IE7+, just like the child selector `>`.

Comment: @lucas clemente: Can you reproduce the issue in jsFiddle?

Comment: I actually tried it in jsFiddle because it wasn't a familiar selector, and it worked fine for me in Chrome.  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: "it wasn't a familiar selector" It should be as familiar as `>`. I'm just going to blame IE6 for this :)

Comment: Yes, it works in jsFiddle. Must be some different issue for me, sorry for that. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @lucas clemente: If you can provide your actual HTML and CSS, I may be able to help out.

Comment: @BoltClock: It's a bit more complicated, I'm actually trying to add row highlighting to the new GMail design. If you want to try it out, just open up GMail and apply this CSS: http://pastebin.com/H6DLAqE6. It somehow doesn't apply the color to the third `tr`.